# How to calculate minimum euclidean distance between two point sets with permutable elements?

Tags: java, set, permutation, points, euclidean-distance

I'm working with two sets of points which always have the same number of elements. A<sub>0</sub>–A<sub>n</sub> and B<sub>0</sub>–B<sub>n</sub>. Both of these sets are non-ordered. **[Image 1]** 
I need to calculate minimum possible euclidean distance between them, taking into account all possible permutations of the elements. The only way I know how to do it is to check all the possible combinations of distances between two points, which makes **n!** number of calculations (40320 combinations for 8 points). **[Image 3]** 
I've tried to see if I can split calculation to multiple smaller calculations **[Image 2]**, but I haven't succeeded. 
 Is there as less computationally expensive way to calculate it?

this is the image

[image]

Comment: How do you define the distance between sets? The sum of individual points to a specific point of the other set, the minimum distance of any point of a set to any point to the other set, the maximum distance between them etc? I am guessing the first one but let's clear it up

Comment: Hm your problem sounds like a special case of Minimum Cost Edge Cover on a Complete Bipartite Graph... See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242294/finding-minimal-cost-edge-cover-for-a-bipartie-graph or look at the Assignment Problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem

Comment: @Eypros: I'm calculating distances between two sets by comparing the specific sequence A0-A7 (as illustrated) with all the possible permutations of the second set B0-B7. As there is 40320 possible permutations of the second set, I get 40320 distance measures between two sets of points. Therefore I define the shortest possible distance between two sets as the shortest one of these 40320 permutations.